# Mysql update if value doesn't exist

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to write quite strange query and i'm having problem with `if` statement, so i have 2 fields `deleted_1` and `deleted_2` in my table which i wanna update, so this how i think it should be:

```
Update `messages`
  if(`deleted_1` == null) SET `deleted_1` = 1
  else
  if(`deleted_2` == null) SET `deleted_2 = 1
  ---and here goes some simple WHERE statements
```

but this doesn't work so basicly i wanna check if `a` field is empty then update it if not check `b` field and if it's empty update `b` field now i'm not sure maybe it's possible to do it in more simple way, i'm quite lost here :)

Comment: Mysql update if value doesn't exist or Mysql INSERT if value doesn't exist ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET deleted_2 = CASE WHEN ISNULL(deleted_1, '') == '' OR ISNULL(deleted_2, '') != '' THEN deleted_2 ELSE 1 END,
    deleted_1 = CASE WHEN ISNULL(deleted_1, '') != '' THEN deleted_1 ELSE 1 END
```

this is saying:

```
deleted_1: will be update if (deleted_1 == null)
deleted_2: will be updated if (deleted_1 != null && deleted_2 == null), 
           This is to match your if else condition
```

Comment: Hmm query goes without errors but it doesn't update any field and even if both fields are empty or only 1 of them is empty

Comment: @Linas I updated the query to account for empty ('') before it would only work if the value is NULL

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is that null != null.  the expression `deleted_2` == null will never resolve as true.  First off, single =, not double (at least in mysql), secondly, try these:

```
mysql> select false = null;
+--------------+
| false = null |
+--------------+
|         NULL |
+--------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select true = null;
+-------------+
| true = null |
+-------------+
|        NULL |
+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select null != null;
+--------------+
| null != null |
+--------------+
|         NULL |
+--------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> select null = null;
+-------------+
| null = null |
+-------------+
|        NULL |
+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Your expression needs to either be "where table.column is null", "where table.column is not null", or some variation of ifnull():  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull